# Typescript - accessing 'hidden' types

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I have the following two packages installed:

```
"@types/ora": "^1.3.1",
"ora": "^1.3.0",
```

I'm trying to use the `Ora` type definition inside of a class, so that I can label a private type before instantiating it.

This works fine:

```
import * as ora from "ora";
const spinner = ora(); // <-- 'spinner' is of Ora type, Intellisense works
```

But, this doesn't...

```
class Test {
  private spinner: Ora; // <-- error. Ora not defined. `ora` doesn't work.
}
```

How do I access 'implicit' types? Should I be augmenting with my own type definitions, or is there an easier way to access the 'hidden' types that are implicitly returned by methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the package does not export the type, you could use `typeof` and a variable of the type, or just use type inference and assign the result of `ora()` which will type the member to the apropriate type:

```
import * as ora from "ora";
const spinner = ora(); 
class Test {
    private spinner: typeof spinner;
    private spinner2 = ora();
}
```

Or if you want to type it without the side effects of calling `ora()`, you could use a helper function:

```
import * as ora from "ora";

function hiddenTypeHelper<T>(fn : (...params:any[])=> T): T {
    return <any> undefined;
}

let oraValue = hiddenTypeHelper(ora);
type oraType = typeof oraValue;

class Test {
    private spinner : oraType;
}
```